# Bermuda grass is invading my Kentucky Blue? Any solutions that don't involve Roundup?

Tags: lawn, grass

I live in the mountain west, where my neighbor's lawn and the mountains nearby allow Bermuda grass to infiltrate my lawn. My neighbor says the only real solution is Roundup; but I'm sure that's not the case. What can I do to discourage growth of the one grass type while promoting growth of the other?

Comment: There is [a discussion on Meta on whether this question belongs in the scope of this site](http://meta.diy.stackexchange.com/questions/128/should-general-questions-on-lawn-maintenance-be-considered-on-topic). Please let us know your opinion!

Answer (score 1):

I've heard of using asphalt shingles as a barrier between grass and flower beds (just dig a trench and bury a line of shingles, may not be pretty but it's effective) and that should stop any more grass from spreading but as for the existing grass you may be forced to either use RoundUp or chop it out and re-seed. I'm not sure of any chemical or other control method that targets Bermuda grass specifically.

Comment: Thank you for your response. I use bricks in the same way as you describe using shingles. Unfortunately, it is not my flower bed that is victim to the Bermuda, but my whole lawn.

Answer (score 1):

I know that Centipede and St. Augustine do not like lime. I have controlled Centipede in my Fescue using extra lime in the area. I don't know how Bermuda tolerates lime but it may be worth experimenting before resulting to killing everything.

Comment: Thank you for your response. I'll try some lime in a corner of my yard and see if I can get the Kentucky Blue to overcome the Bermuda.